# По значению необходимо вывести ключ из словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x

Могу вывести все включи, но отдельный ключ не получается.
Есть словарь:

```
a = {'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb', 'c': 'cc'}
print(a.keys())
```

выход:

```
dict_keys(['a', 'b','c'])
```

А как вывести по отдельному значению его ключ?
Забыл добавить: значения, чьи ключи необходимо найти, должны задаваться с помощью ф-ции input()

Comment: Что если одному значению соответствуют несколько ключей?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, видимо должны все ключи выводится по значению если есть.

Comment: какой результат вы ожидаете для `a = {'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb', 'c': 'cc', 'd':'cc'}` ?

Comment: Не уверен, т.к. с этим случаем не сталкивался еще: может быть что-то вроде: dict_keys(['c', 'd'])

Comment: Но скорее всего будет выводится только первый ключ по порядку: (['c'])

Answer (score 1):

```
key = next((k for k in my_dict if my_dict[k] == value), None)
```

Comment: Думаю, лучше сначала сохранить генератор в переменной, потом получать из него ключи с помощью `next()`, иначе доступ есть только к первому ключу, до остальных потом не добраться. Можно сделать `[k for k in my_dict if my_dict[k] == value]`, чтобы получить список всех ключей с нужным значением.